# before_filter on Model with gsub method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gsub

I have a Customer model with has a attribute named contact_person.
When a Customer gets created, imported as CSV or updated I want to remove "Dhr." or "Mvr." if it exists.

Currently i have a method:

```
def prefix_name
  params[:customer][:contact_person].gsub("Dhr.", "")
  50.times do
    puts("test")
  end
end
```

And i'm running prefix_name with: `before_filter :prefix_name, only: [:import, :create, :update]`

In the server log i see that the method is being called but it does not change the params.

Comment: How did you know params is not changing ? Instead of printing `test`, have you tried printing `params[:customer][:contact_person]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `gsub!` instead of `gsub`

```
params[:customer][:contact_person].gsub!("Dhr.", "")
```